# How to reset material ui tabs when url changes?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

I'm using material-ui tabs within a child component and need to re-render the tab each time the URL changes. 
The url structure is something like:

/in/:id

My simplified code look like this (please ignore if there are vars not included in the sample):

```
class Header extends Component {

  constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.state = {
     selectedTab: 0
    }
   }
   componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
     this.setState({selectedTab: 0});
   }
   render(){

     return (
      <Tabs
       tabItemContainerStyle={style.tabItem}
       className="active-tab-bar tabs"
       initialSelectedIndex={this.state.selectedTab}
      >
      <Tab
        containerElement={<Link to={`/in/${currentClient.id}/timeline`}/>}
        to={`/in/${currentClient.id}/timeline`}
        icon={<FontIcon className="material-icons">playlist_add_check</FontIcon>} />
      <Tab
       containerElement={<Link to=
       {`/in/${currentClient.id}/website`}/>}
       to={`/in/${currentClient.id}/website`}
       icon={<FontIcon className="material-icons">web</FontIcon>} />
      </Tabs>
     )

}
export default withRouter(connect(null, {selectClient})(Header));
```

I tried to use connectWillReceiveProps to reset the selected index to 0 but the tab maintain the selection after url changes. Any thoughts how to reset the tab each time url changes?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your Tabs into a controlled component.

```
render(){

     return (
      <Tabs
       value={this.state.selectedTab}
       onChange={(value)=>this.setState({selectedTab:value})}
       tabItemContainerStyle={style.tabItem}
       className="active-tab-bar tabs"
       initialSelectedIndex={this.state.selectedTab}
      >
      <Tab value=0
        containerElement={<Link to={`/in/${currentClient.id}/timeline`}/>}
        to={`/in/${currentClient.id}/timeline`}
        icon={<FontIcon className="material-icons">playlist_add_check</FontIcon>} />
      <Tab value=1
       containerElement={<Link to=
       {`/in/${currentClient.id}/website`}/>}
       to={`/in/${currentClient.id}/website`}
       icon={<FontIcon className="material-icons">web</FontIcon>} />
      </Tabs>
     )

}
```

Comment: After adding value={this.state.selectedTab}, tabs work but the underline under the selected tab doesn't show at all.

Comment: you can either use `onActive` event of Tab to set a style for the selected element. Or you can change your `this.state.selectedTab` to store the `Link` for the tab and assign it to the `value` prop for the Tab. Hope that works!

Comment: Take a look at this [implementation](https://github.com/SukantGujar/config-server/blob/master/client/chrome/index.js). I have used React Router v4 with material-ui 1. The tabs are working as expected. Shoot questions if needed.

Comment: Did not add another answer as the implementation is in the lines of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the tab props are only for initial : 
"initialSelectedIndex", you need to take the active tab to your control.
replace initialSelectedIndex by :

```
value={this.state.value}
onChange={this.handleChange}
```

and add :

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: 'a',
    };
  }

  handleChange = (value) => {
    this.setState({
      value: value,
    });
  };
```

and now you can change active tab when the url change in willreciveprops...

### full example: (from :http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/tabs)

```
import React from 'react';
import {Tabs, Tab} from 'material-ui/Tabs';`enter code here`

const styles = {
  headline: {
    fontSize: 24,
    paddingTop: 16,
    marginBottom: 12,
    fontWeight: 400,
  },
};

export default class TabsExampleControlled extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: 'a',
    };
  }

  handleChange = (value) => {
    this.setState({
      value: value,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Tabs
        value={this.state.value}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      >
        <Tab label="Tab A" value="a">
          <div>
            <h2 style={styles.headline}>Controllable Tab A</h2>
            <p>
              Tabs are also controllable if you want to programmatically pass them their values.
              This allows for more functionality in Tabs such as not
              having any Tab selected or assigning them different values.
            </p>
          </div>
        </Tab>
        <Tab label="Tab B" value="b">
          <div>
            <h2 style={styles.headline}>Controllable Tab B</h2>
            <p>
              This is another example of a controllable tab. Remember, if you
              use controllable Tabs, you need to give all of your tabs values or else
              you wont be able to select them.
            </p>
          </div>
        </Tab>
      </Tabs>
    );
  }
}
```